# javascript - Trouble to destruct

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

There is an if condition

And the results in `console.log` they prints nothing and appears this at the browser console
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'to' of undefined`
I was alerted that needs to be a destruct object inside object

```js
instance.interceptors.response.use(
        (res) => {
            const { pathname } = window.location;
            const isRedirect = res.status === HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT;

            const data = { isRedirect, data: res.data };

            if (isRedirect) {
                console.log(`pathname: ${pathname}`);
                console.log(`isRedirect: ${isRedirect}`);
                const { redirectDataSource: { to: redirectRoute, ...redirectData } } 
                const {
                    redirectDataSource: { to: redirectRoute, ...redirectData },
                } = res.data.error || res.data;
                console.log(`redirectRoute: ${redirectRoute}`);
                console.log(`redirectDataSource: ${redirectDataSource}`);
            }

            return Promise.resolve(data);
        },
        ...
```

Comment: You need to set a default value for `redirectDataSource`

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add the missing vars

Comment: Shouldn't be there a variable name? `const varname = {`

Comment: @MarkusZeller [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: @MarkusZeller when you're using object destructuring assignment, your variable name(s) are inside the `{}` `const { name } = { id: 1, name: "Fred" }`

Comment: you need to provide default value similar to   const {a: aa = 10, b: bb = 5} = {a: 3};  whenever left hand side object dont have "to" (in your case), it will pick up default value.

Comment: Cool, did not know this also works for objects. Thought just for arrays. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkusZeller well, technically the array destructuring is the only one in ES6, the object destructuring was *officially* added later. But I think both have worked side by side, it's just that the ES6 spec was finalised without object destructuring (as well as other widely supported features at the time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a default value for `redirectDataSource` in case it is undefined

```js
let res = {
  data: {
    error: undefined,
    redirectDataSource: undefined
  }
}

const {
  redirectDataSource: {
    to: redirectRoute,
  } = {to: 'defaultValue'}
} = res.data.error || res.data;

console.log(redirectRoute)
```

Comment: The Code Maniac said that needs to set defaultValue to redirectDataSource and him Answer he set 'defaultValue' to redirectRoute, and is not this that I need to do because after all this the page will redirectioned.

Comment: @VagnerWentz if you don't need a value for `to` you can simply replace `{ to : 'default value '} by `{}`